# I require just a single array output within the foreach loop. How can I accomplish

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

The original data is coming from a database

```php
$sqlKiwi = "SELECT 
    p.id AS page_id, p.project_fk, p.page_name, 
    d.id AS design_id, d.design_name, d.design_note, d.design_cdate,
    v.version_no,
    df.id AS design_feedback_id, df.design_fk AS design_id_in_feedback_tbl, df.design_feedback_cdate,
    ud.user_name,
    ds.design_status, ds.design_status_cdate,
    dr.design_reply_cdate
FROM page p
    LEFT JOIN design d ON d.page_fk = p.id
    LEFT JOIN version v ON v.id = d.version_fk
    LEFT JOIN design_feedback df ON df.design_fk = d.id
    LEFT JOIN design_reply dr ON dr.design_feedback_fk = df.id
    LEFT JOIN design_status ds ON ds.design_fk = d.id
    LEFT JOIN client.user_detail ud ON df.user_detail_fk = ud.id
WHERE p.page_status = 'a'";
$resultKiwi = mysqli_query($conProject, $sqlKiwi);

$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultKiwi)):
    $rows[] = $row;
endwhile;
```

The `$sql` query mentioned above provides all the necessary information to generate the loop. I need to utilize PHP to filter the results accordingly.

```php
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $designName = $row['design_name'];
    $designNameCheck = (!empty($designName )) ? $designName : "nil";
    $pageName = $row['page_name'];
    $pageId = $row['page_id'];
    $designStatus = $row['design_status'];

    $foo[$pageName.'-'.$pageId][$designNameCheck][] = array(
        'status' => array(
            'status' => $designStatus,
        )
    );
}
```

Output

```
{
    "About Us-33": {
        "about-us-v1": [
            {
                "status": {
                    "status": "r"
                }
            }
        ],
        "about-us-v2": [
            {
                "status": {
                    "status": "r"
                }
            }
        ],
        "about-us-v3": [
            {
                "status": {
                    "status": "r"
                }
            },
            {
                "status": {
                    "status": "a"
                }
            }
        ],
        "about-us-v4": [
            {
                "status": {
                    "status": null
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "Home-32": {
        "nil": [
            {
                "status": {
                    "status": null
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "Client-34": {
        "nil": [
            {
                "status": {
                    "status": null
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
```

What Iam looking is that the about-us-v3 array, which possesses two statuses: r and a. The objective is to produce a singular output for each distinct array. If the status `a` exists in an array, output `a`. else the status `a` is absent, then output `r`.

```php
...
    "about-us-v3": [
        {
            "status": {
                "status": "a"
            }
        }
    ],
...
```

In the table below, the row for about-us-v3 appears twice, associated with the statuses 'r' and 'a', respectively. As previously indicated, if the 'a' status is present, 'r' need to be removed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need multiple statuses, don't make `$foo[$pageName.'-'.$pageId][$designNameCheck]` an array, just set it to the status. Then you can replace it easily with `a` if it already contains `r`.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $designName = $row['design_name'];
    $designNameCheck = (!empty($designName )) ? $designName : "nil";
    $pageName = $row['page_name'];
    $pageId = $row['page_id'];
    $designStatus = $row['design_status'];

    if (!isset($foo[$pageName.'-'.$pageId][$designNameCheck])) { // nothing there, save this value
        $foo[$pageName.'-'.$pageId][$designNameCheck] = $designStatus;
    } elseif ($designStatus == 'a') { // 'a' always takes precedence
        $foo[$pageName.'-'.$pageId][$designNameCheck] = $designStatus;
    } elseif ($foo[$pageName.'-'.$pageId][$designNameCheck] != 'a') { // don't replace 'a' with 'r'
        $foo[$pageName.'-'.$pageId][$designNameCheck] = $designStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to break my head for the past 2 days to get this thing to work. I know I was overthinking. Thanks for the help.